# Excel column: If cell value is 0 replace with value from cell to the left

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, microsoft-excel-2019

I am an excel novice. I have started working with data strings of over 1000 rows. Some cells in a column have 0 values and must be replaced with the value of the cell to the left. Currently, I copy and paste to get the correct data. This takes hours. Surely that must be a better way or a function I can use?
In the picture below. All 0 values in column E must be replaced with the value of the cell in column D. The same goes for column G, the 0 values in column G must be replaced with the value of the cell in column D.
So. E4 0 replace with the value in D4. And G5 0 replace with the value in D5.

0 value in E4 replace with value of D4
[image]

Can anyone please help with a formula? I use Excel 2019 professional.

Comment: You can't have a formula replace an existing value (i.e. the cell either has the formula or the value, but can't have both). That said, you could use a helper column, or some VBA to accomplish what you want

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: Consider using a VBA to accomplish this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second Sheet and "duplicate" your data there by typing `=Sheet1!A1` *(e.g. `=$Sheet1.A1` in LibreOffice)* in the upper left cell and copy/paste that for all (relevant!) data-occupied cells.

In this new Sheet you will then have the option to fill in formulas;
as in `=IF(Sheet1!A1<>0; Sheet1!A1; Sheet1!B1)`
to copy the value from B1 instead, if A1 is 0.

*`;` comes from my Swedish locale, your locale might require `,`*